# Say $X_n$ takes values in open interval $(a,b)$ and $\lim X_n = z$. Does $z$ take value in that interval?

Tags: real-analysis

Say $X_n$ takes values in open interval $(a,b)$ and $\lim X_n = z$. 
Does $z$ take values in open interval $(a,b)$?

I think the statement is false, but I can't come up with any counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$, for all positive integers $n$. Each term is in the open interval $(0,2)$, but what is the limit?

Comment: so since the limit is 0 and that is not in the open interval (0,2) the statement would be false right?

Comment: That's correct.